# Batch export torrent files from KTorrent

Tags: automation, batch, torrent-client, ktorrent

To export single torrent file:

Right mouse click -> Advanced -> Export Torrent

To export n torrent files:

???

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the directory ~/.kde/share/apps/ktorrent
inside you'll have one directory torN (where N starts from 0) for each torrent. Inside there is a file named ***torrent*** that has the content that is exported as single file. You can then write a script to copy all tor[0..n]/torrent to a destination, renaming each file so it's not overwritten.